# App.yaml error expected <block end>, but found '-'

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have the follow app.yaml:

```
application: myapp
version: 3
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /
  script: main.php

- url: /src
  static_dir: src

  - url: /vendor
  static_dir: vendor
```

But, when i deploy it, the console shows the error:

```
appcfg.py: error: Error parsing C:\app.yaml: w
hile parsing a block mapping
  in "C:\app.yaml", line 15, column 3
expected <block end>, but found '-'
  in "C:\app.yaml", line 18, column 3.
```

The code is like Google reference in `https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref`

What is wrong with it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy my code, there were too many spaces in some part. It works.

```
application: myapp
version: 3
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /
  script: main.php

- url: /src
  static_dir: src

- url: /vendor
  static_dir: vendor
```

Comment: It works, thanks!!! But... i don't undestand what was wrong...  App.yaml do not support spaces?

Comment: - url: /vendor (line 18) contained too many spaces. You can noticed on your code and that's why it generated errors.

Comment: Huum ok... I thinked it don't would cause problems... Thanks again :)

Comment: Done. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error earlier today and i found the easiest way to fix problems like these and other indentation problem in yaml config file.

check out [www.yamllint.com](http://www.yamllint.com)

**How it works**

Open the URL and copy your yaml configuration file into the blank page and paste (of course, you can tweak your sensitive information so you don't leak them). What this does is, fix the indentations issues and point out the exact location and by how much space you need to adjust.

To read more indepth documentations about Yaml Lint, click [YamlLint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable)